# Plot Viewer is not working anymore - how to fix?

Tags: matplotlib, visual-studio-code, jupyter

I am currently working with VS Code and the Jupyter Extension. Until today the GUI of the Extension looked like this: [old gui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KDvua.png)

But today this GUI changed to something like this: [new gui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fzwxr.png)

Problem is: If I now plot something I cannot open it in the Plot Viewer (before: double-clicking on the image would open it in a new file) but only save it in very low quality:
[old version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c8Yw9.png)
vs.
[new version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v4TJY.png)

The 'Expand Image' Button is gone and now there is only a 'Save As' Button.

The GUI only changes to the newer version if I reopen the files. As long as a file is open in VS Code the old GUI remains and I can still open the images.

I already tried out to use older version of the Jupyter Extension, but it did not help.

If you need more in order to help, please write it and I will provide it.
The problem is probably very trivial but at this point, I am just very confused.

Thanks in advance and have a great day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I've found out that the Plot Viewer is no longer supported but will be added again soon.
Until then, if you want to use the Plot Viewer you need to do the following:

1. Install an older version of the Yupiter Extension (2021.2.0 worked for me).

- this version does not work with the newest version of vs code

2. Install older Version of VS Code (https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_57 worked for me).
   After VS Code is installed you can open it and disable the auto update inside the VS Code settings.

Now you should be able to work with the old Jupyter Extension that includes the Plot Viewer.
If you update the Jupyter Extension you will need to do the above steps again.

Maybe this can help some lost souls searching for the old Plot Viewer.

Comment: At the moment you can also download the Visual Studio Code Insiders and install the newest version of the Yupiter Extension.

Comment: very interesting. So we are in January 2022 and this seems to still be an issue.